# Cannot scroll after converting existing angularjs app to ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an existing angularjs app which was working fine until I converted it to ionic. I tested the website on the chrome browser and discovered that I can no longer scroll down to see a long table.

The only change I made was in the html code;

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes, width=device-width">
  <title>test-view</title>

  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/ionic/js/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/ionic/js/bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>

  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!--<script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="../../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <script src="lib/ionic/js/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/bower_components/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>

  <script src="lib/ionic/js/bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.js"></script>

  <div ng-include src="'partials/header.html'"></div>
</head>
<body>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers-func.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="ViewCtrl" class="container">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>

      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>symbol</th>
      </tr>

      <thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="vw $data">
        <td data-title="'name'" >
          {{vw.name}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'symbol'">
          {{vw.symbol}}
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to make the code scrollable?

Comment: I don't have to explicitly add scroll code for the angularjs app. It could work on any desktop browser. It is only after adding ionic that scroll stopped working.

Comment: you need to re-think about what piece of your page you need to scroll... like an android (or others) app... take a look on ionic list component

Comment: (sorry for my first comment, I did think to be a timeout problem)

Comment: @Joaozito Polo, pardon my ignorance. I have never written an android app.  For android apps, does one have to add explicitly add code to support scrolling? It cannot be supported automatically like a normal angularjs app for browser? Is it possible to just use cordova (without using ionic js) to convert the existing app to apk and have scrolling work?

Comment: no problem. On android, initially all screen is fixed... and then, you need to choice some component to scroll, like a picture gallery, or a list. On native android, you can also to create a scrollable panel around all your page... but I try to find at ionic now, and I not found similar function. The most similar is list, I believe: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#list

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to adjust my thinking when moving from browser apps to mobile apps. Didn't realize that even simple scrolling need to be supported explicitly. I thought such things would just work automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap this tag over your table.

```
<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true">
<!-- table contents here -->
</ion-content>
```

The above code will use native scroll instead of js scroll. Note that it may not work with lower versions of Android. As long as you are using Android 4.2 and above, you are quite safe.

Since you are adding a html partial, I assume there is a header on your html. Therefore, use `class="has-header"`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I found that this forced scrollbars to always show on desktop browsers, so to set them to show only when necessary I added this CSS: `.overflow-scroll { overflow-y: auto; }`